# Phonegap filetransfer working in iPhone simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, cordova

The following bit of code works fine in my iPhone simulator. I'm tried with IOS 5.1 using Cordova 1.6 and also tried with 1.7. My external hosts entry is configured to 127.0.0.1

This is the code:

```
          function uploadPhoto(imageElement){
               var options = new FileUploadOptions();
               var options = new FileUploadOptions();
               options.fileKey="file";
               options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
               options.fileName="carimage.jpg";
               options.chunkedMode = true;
               var params = new Object();
               params.value1 = "Car";
               params.value2 = "Used";

               options.params = params;
               options.chunkedMode = false;

               var ft = new FileTransfer();
               console.log("Upload Photo");
               ft.upload(
                         document.getElementById(imageElement).src,
                         "http://127.0.0.1:8080/claim/image",
                         win, 
                         fail,
                         options, 
                         true);
               console.log("Done Uploading");
           }

           function win(r) {
               console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
               console.log("Response = " + r.response);
               console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
           }

           function fail(error) {
               alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
               console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
               console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
           }
```

The simulator output in Xcode is:

```
2012-05-09 12:45:09.390 motorazzi[24964:13403] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-05-09 12:48:28.421 motorazzi[24964:13403] [INFO] Upload Photo
2012-05-09 12:48:28.484 motorazzi[24964:13403] [INFO] Done Uploading
2012-05-09 12:48:40.662 motorazzi[24964:13403] [INFO] Code = 200
2012-05-09 12:48:40.662 motorazzi[24964:13403] [INFO] Response = 
2012-05-09 12:48:40.663 motorazzi[24964:13403] [INFO] Sent = 1358
```

Which is fine, but using the device from Xcode, I get:

```
2012-05-09 12:51:40.537 motorazzi[885:707] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-05-09 12:51:56.554 motorazzi[885:707] [INFO] Upload Photo
2012-05-09 12:51:56.654 motorazzi[885:707] [INFO] Done Uploading
2012-05-09 12:51:56.748 motorazzi[885:707] File Transfer Error: Could not connect to the server.
2012-05-09 12:51:56.798 motorazzi[885:707] [INFO] An error has occurred: Code = 3
2012-05-09 12:51:56.803 motorazzi[885:707] [INFO] upload error source http://127.0.0.1:8080/claim/image
2012-05-09 12:51:56.813 motorazzi[885:707] [INFO] upload error target file:///var/mobile/Applications/699481A7-C598-43BA-BDCA-962DEF925EE5/tmp/photo_020.jpg
```

On my server log I can see that the device is not connecting at all. Is there anything that I may be doing wrong, or should be checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running on the device the IP address 127.0.0.1 or "localhost" is the device itself. That is why you are not hitting your server. You will have to put in the host name or IP address of the server that is hosting your upload script.

Also, make sure you whitelist the server in your plist or it will get rejected.